# Add tracking to slideshow to see how many slides are viewed

Tags: jquery, onclick, google-analytics, slideshow, tagging

I frequently use a jQuery slideshow and have received a request to figure out a way to measure how far people get into the show using Google Analytics- i.e. are they viewing all the slides, or stopping after #3, #4, etc.

I would usually add an onClick event tag to track it (you can see examples of this in the HTML below), but in this case, it wouldn't work because the navigation arrows don't change at all, so I'm not sure how to tie the specific slide the person is viewing to their click action.

I've looked on SO and the internet and can't find any ideas on how to achieve this. The only thing I can think of is to reprogram the slider so all the content changes, including the navigation arrows so I can assign a unique click event to the arrow tied to the slide showing when it is clicked.  I don't think the slideshow would be as slick this way though and I would like to keep it as is.  I would also like to keep all the slides on one URL so the whole site doesn't reload with each click.

Thanks in advance for any advice.  [A working example is here](http://cookware.lecreuset.com/cookware/content_Le-Creuset-Atelier_10151_-1_20002), but in case you need it, here is the jQuery code for the slideshow:

```
            <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
            var thumbs = $('ul.thumbHolder li');
            var thumbs = $('ul.thumbHolder li');
            var bigImgs = $('ul.imgHolder li');
            var mask = $('.imgHolder');
            var imgW = $('ul.imgHolder li').width();
            var speed = 300;

            thumbs.removeClass('selected').first().addClass('selected');

            thumbs.click(function() {
                var target = $(this).index();

                mask.animate({'left':'-'+imgW*target+'px'},speed);


                thumbs.removeClass('selected');
                $(this).addClass('selected');
            });

            $('.Bleft').on('click',function() {
                var i = $('ul.thumbHolder li.selected').index();
                i--;

                $('ul.thumbHolder li.selected').removeClass('selected');
                thumbs.eq(i).addClass('selected');

                if ( i === -1 ) { mask.animate({'left':'-'+imgW*$('ul.thumbHolder li').index()+'px'},speed); }
                else{ mask.animate({'left':'-'+imgW*i+'px'},speed); }
                clearInterval(counter);
            });
            $('.Bright').on('click',function() {
                var i = $('ul.thumbHolder li.selected').index();
                i = i >= thumbs.length-1 ? 0 : i+1;

                $('ul.thumbHolder li.selected').removeClass('selected');
                thumbs.eq(i).addClass('selected');

                mask.animate({'left':'-'+imgW*i+'px'},speed);
                clearInterval(counter);
            });


            var count = 0;
            var counter = window.setInterval(timer, 5000); 
            function timer() {
                count=count+0;
                if (count >= 0) { count = 0;    return;    }
                mask.animate({'left':'-'+ imgW*count +'px'},speed);
                thumbs.removeClass('selected');
                thumbs.eq(count).addClass('selected');
            }

            });

            </script>
```

and here is the HTML:

```
        <div id="slideshow-container">
        <div class="control Bleft"></div>
        <div class="control Bright"></div>
        <div class="mask">

        <ul class="imgHolder">
        <li>
            <div id="office-tour-slide01">
                <p>In April we rolled out the orange carpet to celebrate the grand opening of our new North American Marketing Office and Culinary Center. L’Atelier Le Creuset (French for “The Le Creuset Workshop”) is situated on the banks of the Ashley River in Charleston, SC.<br /><br />The front entrance to the nearly 9,000 square feet of renovated office space is flanked by entirely edible landscaping. Fresh herbs such as mint, thyme and cilantro are put to good use in our Atelier kitchen.
        </p>
                <img width="900" height="425" src="/wcsstore/CVWEB/images/home/office-slide_01.jpg" alt="Front Entrance"  /> 
            </div><!--//END office-tour-slide01-->
        </li>
        <li>
            <div id="office-tour-slide02">
                 <p>The glass walled boardroom is more than just a meeting space. It also doubles as a museum for a few of our heritage pieces. The lighting pattern on the ceiling subtly mimics our three-ring logo.</p>
                 <img width="900" height="425" src="/wcsstore/CVWEB/images/home/office-slide_02.jpg" alt="Le Creuset Board Room"  />

            </div><!--//END office-tour-slide02-->
        </li>
        <li>
            <div id="office-tour-slide07">
                <p>A white marble counter just outside the conference room showcases our newest sun-inspired color, <a href="/cookware/CatalogSearchResultCmd?storeId=10151&catalogId=20002&langId=-1&docType=1&searchTerm=Soleil&shopBy=color" onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent','Office Tour', 'Click', 'Soleil']);">Soleil</a>. The backlit seagrass panel is a nod to our coastal location.</p>
                <img width="900" height="425" src="/wcsstore/CVWEB/images/home/office-slide_07.jpg" alt="Soleil Showcase"  />

            </div><!--//END office-tour-slide07-->
        </li>
        <li>
            <div id="office-tour-slide03">
                <p>Even the bathrooms feature an unexpected twist— <a href="/cookware/product_Goose-Pot_10151_-1_20002_83103" onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent','Office Tour', 'Click', 'GoosePot']);">Goose pots</a> – yes, goose pots! – double as sink basins.</p>
                <img width="900" height="425" src="/wcsstore/CVWEB/images/home/office-slide_03.jpg" alt="Le Creuset Sinks"  />

            </div><!--//END office-tour-slide03-->
        </li>
        <li>
            <div id="office-tour-slide04">
                <p>While the <a href="/cookware/content_Le-Creuset-Truckette_10151_-1_20002" onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent','Office Tour', 'Click', 'Truckette']);">Le Creuset Truckette</a> has to stay parked outside, our custom vintage-style cruiser brings a bit of whimsy to the lobby.</p>
                <img width="900" height="425" src="/wcsstore/CVWEB/images/home/office-slide_04.jpg" alt="Le Creuset Beach Cruiser"  />

            </div><!--//END office-tour-slide04-->
        </li>
        <li>
            <div id="office-tour-slide05">
                <p>An open workspace allows for both collaboration and optimal light exposure. The center island acts as a runway for our collection of pots autographed by our favorite chefs.</p>
                <img width="900" height="425" src="/wcsstore/CVWEB/images/home/office-slide_05.jpg" alt="Le Creuset Studio"  />

            </div><!--//END office-tour-slide05-->
        </li>
        <li>
            <div id="office-tour-slide06">
                <p>L’Atelier – the workshop – is a fully equipped demonstration kitchen with the highest-quality Miele appliances. Intended to be a hub for community activity, it’s already hosted our first Guest Chef, with a second soon to follow. Our Guest Chef Series invites innovative chefs to prepare dishes and demonstrate techniques to a ticketed audience.</p>
                <img width="900" height="425" src="/wcsstore/CVWEB/images/home/office-slide_06.jpg" alt="L’Atelier"  />

            </div><!--//END office-tour-slide06-->
        </li>
        <li>
            <div id="office-tour-slide08">
                 <p>Our communications team maintains a media wall with tears and inspirations from recent photo shoots, magazines and campaigns.</p>
                <img width="900" height="425" src="/wcsstore/CVWEB/images/home/office-slide_08.jpg" alt="Communications Team Wall"  />

            </div><!--//END office-tour-slide08-->
        </li>
        <li>
            <div id="office-tour-slide09">
                <a href="/cookware/product_Herb-Planter_10151_-1_20002_89624" onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent','Office Tour', 'Click', 'HerbPlanter']);">
                    <img width="162" height="279" src="/wcsstore/CVWEB/images/home/office-slide_08_01.jpg" alt="Plant Your Own Herbs: Herb Planter"  />
                </a>
                <a href="/cookware/product_5-Shelf-Cookware-Display-Stand_10151_-1_20002_10056" onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent','Office Tour', 'Click', '5ShelfCookwareDisplayStand']);">
                    <img width="174" height="279" src="/wcsstore/CVWEB/images/home/office-slide_08_02.jpg" alt="Display Your Cookware: 5 Shelf Cookware Display Stand"  />
                </a>
                <a href="/cookware/product_5-1%2F2-qt.-Round-French-Oven_10151_-1_20002_10138" onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent','Office Tour', 'Click', '512qtRoundFrenchOven']);">
                    <img width="167" height="279" src="/wcsstore/CVWEB/images/home/office-slide_08_03.jpg" alt="Stock Your Shelves: 5 1/2 qt. Round French Oven"  />
                </a>
                <a href="/cookware/product_16-Piece-Dinnerware-Set_10151_-1_20002_10168_24076" onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent','Office Tour', 'Click', '16PieceDinnerwareSet']);">
                    <img width="202" height="279" src="/wcsstore/CVWEB/images/home/office-slide_08_04.jpg" alt="Feed a Crowd: 16-Piece Dinnerware Set"  />
                </a>        
                <a href="/cookware/content_cooking-techniques-ruhlman_10151_-1_20002" onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent','Office Tour', 'Click', 'Ruhlman']);">
                    <img width="195" height="279" src="/wcsstore/CVWEB/images/home/office-slide_08_05.jpg" alt="Learn to Cook: Technique Series from Michael Ruhlman"  />
                </a>    
            </div><!--//END office-tour-slide09-->
        </li>
        </ul>
        </div>
        <div style="clear: both;"></div>
        <div id="office-tour-nav" style="display: none;">
        <ul class="thumbHolder">
           <li>&nbsp;</li>
           <li>&nbsp;</li>
           <li>&nbsp;</li>
           <li>&nbsp;</li>
           <li>&nbsp;</li>
           <li>&nbsp;</li>
           <li>&nbsp;</li>
           <li>&nbsp;</li>
           <li>&nbsp;</li>   
        </ul>
        </div><!--//END soleil-nav-->
        </div><!--//END slideshow-container-->
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the things that I've done to track click through was by adding the event click.

Uses analytics.js

In your "a" tag -> `onclick="ga('send','event','CATEGORY', 'ACTION', 'LABEL')"`

**Event Tracking**

Google's [Event Tracking Documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events) (analytics.js)

**User Timings**

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingTiming